Combinations -arranging Groups of Identical Items in two distinct rows.
I have encountered the following permutations question:
How many ways are there to arrange 4 different types of fruit, 3 of each kind into 2 rows with six pieces of fruit in each row.
I think that the answer to the problem is $\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}$ to account for the 4 groups of 3 identical pieces of fruit. I cannot however figure out how the two rows come into play in the question.
The answer given to the problem is $\frac{12!}{6!6!}$. I don't understand where the $6!6!$ is coming from. Obviously it is somehow related to the row but I don't understand the logic here.
Any clarity in the matter would be appreciated.

I have two reactions to your posted question, which I upvoted:
First of all, by my interpretation of the question, your computation of $~\displaystyle \frac{12!}{(3!)^4}~$ is right.
Further, assuming that we have interpreted the question accurately, I also question why there are two rows, instead of one row with $~12~$ positions.
Even if you assume that the rows were (somehow) indistinguishable, rather than one row in front of another, the adjustment would simply be to apply an over-counting adjustment factor of $~\dfrac{1}{2!}.~$

Second of all, suppose that you and I have both misinterpreted the question, with the official solution being $~\displaystyle \binom{12}{6}.~$
Apparently, the official solution reflects how many ways there are to randomly select $~6~$ positions out of $~12~$ positions.
The best that I can reverse-engineer is that the official solution would make sense if there were $~2~$ types of fruit, with $~6~$ of each fruit type.

I was wondering the same thing about the interpretation of the question as well but then as you said we would need to have a different distribution types of fruit (2 types of 6 each). It is interesting because the next question in the series has the same distribution of fruit (4 kinds of 3 each) but then wants those to be arranged in 3 rows of 4 rather than 2 rows of six. The solution for part "b" is $\frac{12!}{4!4!4!}$ again implying that row placement plays some role here. No matter which way I look at it, I can't make sense of the given solution.

@DBack Perhaps a typo, where the problem composer actually intended $~2~$ types of fruit, with $~6~$ of each fruit type.  Further, the existence of two rows could be a red herring, designed to attempt to mislead the problem solver into thinking that the computation would be different than if there was one row of $~12~$ positions.
